# How to change column value based on fuzzy wuzzy score

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fuzzywuzzy

I have a dataframe with a column including makes of cars. I want to apply where and fuzzywuzzy to improve the data. For example if an entry has an 80% match with the word Mercedes I want it to be replaced with the word Mercedes. This is what I have so far

```
df = df.where(fuzz.ratio(df['make'], "Mercedes") >= 80,"Mercedes")
```

I also tried this

```
df.mask (df[fuzz.ratio(df['make'], 'Mercedes') >= 85], 'Mercedes', inplace=True)
```

I get the same error both times

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

df.where is the function https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html. I think I understand the error and I get that my syntax is not correct but I cant not figure out another method. Also preferably, a very fast method is ideal, as the dataframe is very big

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. you're passing the entire Series to `fuzz.ratio` (this throws the error). Use `apply` to apply `fuzz.ratio` to the Series values
2. `df.where` replaces values where the condition is `False`, so use `<80`

This should work:

```
df.where(df['make'].apply(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x, "Mercedes")) < 80,"Mercedes")
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly

Comment: You're welcome. Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it solved your issue.